# LibGDX strange status bar in background [BUG]

Tags: android, libgdx, bug

I released an app and I noticed that some devices has a strange "bug" which I don't know if it's caused by Android, me or LibGDX.

That bug is related to status bar, normally app let you see the bar (time, battery percentage ...). In my app the statusbar shouldn't be showed but it seems to exist in some devices.

What is strange is that the bar isn't the same of the device but a general bar with random time and battery percentage. Sometimes the bar showed is an older Android version.

Comment: Can you post your `android:theme` config ? and did you use immersive mode or not ? and did you change your `MainActivity` window by adding some flags to it?In which version of android you have this bug ?

Comment: @Saeed This bug is also in other famous app. This is Android's fault